# NodeJS: How to wait for a for-loop of async requests to complete before proceeding with code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am relatively new to node and trying to create an web app that allows users to get retrieve information from the youtube api by providing a list of youtube channel IDs(already in server) by going to my `/retrieve` route.

Currently I am looping through an array of objects with channel IDs, and for each ID I use a `setTimeOut` function to send 1request/500ms (due limitations of the youtube API) and using the `request.get` request module. I am trying to continue code and `res.send` AFTER all the requests to youtube is completed. Furtherfore, for each data obj I received from each youtube request, I am parsing and pushing them to the `youtubeinfo` array.

I have a nodeJS version of v12.16.3.

Here's my code below, sorry for the messiness:

```
var youtubeinfo = []

router.get('/retrieve', async function(req, res, next) {

  const length = datajs.length
  console.log(length);
  var promiseArray = [];

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
          const channelID = listOfID[i]['Channel ID']
          const url = youtubeAPIChannelID.concat(apiKey)

          request.get(url, (err, response, data)=>{
            if (!err) {

              parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
              if (parsedData.items){

                const parsedYoutubeobj = {
                "custom_collection": {
                  "title": parsedData.items[0].brandingSettings.channel.title,
                  "body_html": parsedData.items[0].brandingSettings.channel.description,
                  "image": {
                    "src": parsedData.items[0].brandingSettings.image.bannerImageUrl,
                    "alt": "Rails Logo"
                  }
                }
              }
              youtubeinfo.push(parsedYoutubeobj)
              console.log("----------------------")

              console.log(parsedYoutubeobj);
              youtubeinfo.push(parsedYoutubeobj);
              resolve()
              } else {
                console.log("something is wrong...check if youtube channel still exist")
                reject(error)
              }

            } else{
              console.log("statusCode: "+ response.statusCode)
              console.log("err: "+ err);
              reject(error)

            }
          })
      }, 500 * i);
    }(i));
  }))
  }
  res.send(await Promise.all(promiseArray));
});
```

How can I correctly apply `promises/async/await` to have my code continue after all the async requests are made?
I figured that using promises here would a solution. How do I edit `res.send(await Promise.all(promiseArray));` to send a string after all promise in promiseArray resolves?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function in `router.get` needs to be `async`:

```
router.get('/retrieve', async function(req, res, next) {
...
}
```

Comment: I just fixed that, but how do I res.send() like a string after all the requests is done? Thank you!

Comment: Depends on what you want to return from the request?

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to use `Promise.all` here since it will make the requests in parallel. Simply use a `for..of` loop instead with a 500ms wait in between each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pooling. You can implement your own pooling ffor this , or you can use a pooling library.

This possibly is not a one-liner problem..

Just for reference (maybe there are better libraries):
https://github.com/eetay/promise-pool-js

Comment: another solution would be promise.all with try-catch, but possibly will be instable and resource hungry.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Promise.all(promiseArray).then(values => res.send(JSON.stringify())
```